# Fetch Request never seems to complete

Tags: javascript, vue.js, proxy, vuejs3

This code was in a previous question, so I moved it to a new question as they not unrelated...

Me again with the same code, but a different problem... I have my app setup, and running on an express server with a proxy to talk to the API server, my code is outlined below

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Is That Legit?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
          <img alt="Site logo" class="logo" src="assets/logo.svg" width="333" height="187" />
        </header>
        <h1 class="app-title">Is User Legit</h1>
        <input @input="saveID" placeholder="User ID" />
        <button @click="checkID">Check Customer is Legit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.9/dist/vue.global.js" defer></script>
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My App.js is setup like this, fairly standard:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      customerID: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveID(event) {
      this.customerID = event.target.value;
    },
    async checkID() {
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'x-api-key': 'ThisIsMyAPIKeyThereIsNoOtherLikeIt'
        }
      }
      const url = `/checkCustomer?customerNumber=${this.customerID}`;
      try {
        const result = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await result.json();
        console.log(json);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

my server.js (which is powered by ExpressJS) is also below...

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const cors = require('cors');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

// app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('dist'));
app.use('/dist', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + 'dist/index.html');
});
app.use('/dist/assets/main.css', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + 'dist/assets/main.css');
});
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ['https://myAPI.com'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
  })
);
app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With')
});

// Add middleware for http proxy
const options = {
    target: 'https://myAPI.com', // target host
    pathRewrite: {
        '^/checkCustomer' : ''
    },
    router: {
        'localhost:3000': 'https://myAPI.com',
    },
};
const apiProxy = (req, res) => {
    createProxyMiddleware(options);
}
app.use('/checkCustomer', apiProxy);

https.createServer(
    {
        key: fs.readFileSync("thisIsMyServerKey.key"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync("thisIsMyServerCert.cert"),
    },
    app
).listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on: https://localhost:3000');
});
```

So I run `npm run start` to fire up my `server.js` no problem, and the aim is to populate the input box with a customer ID and hit the "Are They Legit?" button to check if a customer is real or not, the proxy jumps in checking for the `/checkCustomer` it then removes the `/checkCustomer` and appends the rest of the URL tot he API url and submits it.

However this doesn't appear to be the case, and the request just never completes.

Everything is currently configured the way it is to try and resolve an issue with CORS.

I tried a few articles/Q&A on stackOverflow, googling a few solutions, but nothing has come to fruition, this was the closest I have got.

Would someone be able to guide me in fixing this?

Comment: Without running your code, can you browse directly to the fetched URL and get a result? It’s possible [you’re not catching HTTP error codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

Comment: yes, i can browse directly to the code, which is why this is frustrating :/

Answer (score 0):

So I refactored this properly in vite, and it works fine :/ My vite setup is below

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import VueDevTools from 'vite-plugin-vue-devtools'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), VueDevTools()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/checkUserIsValid': {
        target: 'https://linkToMyAPIServer/URL/for/QUERY',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/checkUserIsValid/, '')
      },
      cors: false
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```